# How to test CSRF protection on Spring?

Tags: java, spring, csrf

If I am not mistaken, CSRF protection is enabled by default with the Java configuration.
Currently on my Spring Boot Project I have created a configuration class in which I have set a control that allows you to disable the CSRF protection, as follows:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(value = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 1987)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Value("${security.enable.csrf}")
    private boolean csrfEnabled;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        // exclude some services from authentication
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/security",
                        "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/csrf", "favicon.ico", "/graphiql", "/vendor/**",
                        "/subscriptions", "/altair")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**");
    }

    /* Disables CSRF */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().xssProtection().and().contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self'");

//      CSRF protection is enabled by default with Java configuration. 
//      If you would like to disable CSRF, the corresponding Java 
//      configuration can be seen below.
//      If you want to disable CSRF you have to set 
//      security.enable.csrf = false in application.yml
        if (csrfEnabled == false) {
            http.csrf().disable();
            logger.info("CSRF HAS BEEN DISABLE");
            // Else CSRF is enable
        } else {
            logger.info("CSRF IS ENABLE");
        }
    }
}
```

But how can I check if the CSRF protection really remains active or is deactivated?